# Python 3.4.3 Regex, matching a strings that end in certain pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am attempting to complete #25 on [this](http://www.ling.gu.se/~lager/python_exercises.html) for reference.

What I need to do is make a regular expression that matches a string in the case that it ends with the pattern of consonant vowel consonant.

```
    case_3 = re.compile('([b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z])$')
```

This is what I have so far. From what I understand, this should match any string that lies in desired pattern but clearly I am mistaken. It only matches for strings that are OF that speciific pattern. For example "tah" will be matched but "ttah" will not be. How can I make this happen?

Comment: You're probably using `re.match` instead of `re.search` -- or in your case `case_3.search(...)`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot actually. been having a hard time with learning regular expressions but after reading more on the differences between these two and the callable functions on match objects, I am beginning to see how they can be used.

Comment: If you did manage to find an answer to your question do add it as an answer. We all will be eager to learn from it :)